# Is there any way to obtain an XAConnection or XAResource object from WSJdbcDataSource object?

Tags: jakarta-ee, db2, websphere, jndi, xa

I have tried in vain multiple approaches to obtain an XADataSource from Websphere doing a JNDI lookup..I have previously asked that qn in a different discussion.

However, I realise i do not need to obtain an instance of XADataSource(DB2XADataSource in particular) from Websphere. I need just the XAConnection object or XAResource to be able to enlist/delist an XA resource to participate in a Transaction.

Is there any way i can obtain that from Websphere? Or is there any other approach to doing a jndi lookup for a datasource with WAS, but not using websphere's WSJdbcDataSource class.

Comment: You should not enlist/delist resources yourself, that should be managed by the framework itself. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Atomikos as a TM provides the feature for managing the enlisting/delisting of resources, if i want to do tht. It requires  the XAResource instance. What I have is a web app using jndi and a similar java class using jdbc to call upon 2 DB2 databases. At a given time, only 1 will b called though. What i want is having a single transaction handling class which uses Atomikos TM functionalitites to handle both scenarios

Comment: I don't remember the details, but I'm pretty sure you shouldn't mess with enlismtent/delistment yourself. Atomkios TM offers enlisment/delisment so that the app server can do its job. You can read an (old) blog post of mine: http://www.ewernli.com/web/guest/51 where I drew a sequence diagram of how things should go. You see the interaction between the three parts: (1) the application, (2) the app server and (3) the transaction manager.

Comment: @ewernli: tht blog was interesting bt srry it didnt help much in this specific problem.

Comment: I don't know if your scenario here is related to you other question about testing failure of 2PC. It is very unclear to me what you want to achieve here.